# An operating system wasn't found

Tags: boot, operating-systems

When I boot my computer, it boots fine.

When I restart it though, I get the following error:

> An operating system wasn't found. Try disconnecting any drives that don't contain an operating system.
>
> Press Ctrl+Alt+Del to restart

My BIOS is recently updated. The error happened before the update still.

I am running Windows 8.1 x64.

My computer specification is as follows. I have put what I hope to be the relevant information nearest to the top.

```
Motherboard

    Name                                    ASUS M5A97 EVO R2.0

BIOS
Name                                    To be filled by O.E.M.
Description                             2005
Vendor                                  American Megatrends Inc.
Version                                 2005
Date                                    20130916

Harddisk 0
Name                                    WDC WD5001AALS-00L3B2
Description                             Disk drive
Vendor                                  (Standard disk drives)
Capacity                                476938 MB
Interface Type                          SATA
Serial Number                           WD-WMASZ0136444
Firmware Revision                       01.03B01
Model Number                            WDC WD5001AALS-00L3B2
Removable                               false
Support DMA                             true
Support LBA                             true
Support SATA                            true
SATA Generation                         Gen 2
Sector Total                            268435455
Maximum Queue Depth                     31
Highest Supported ATA Version           8
Security Supported                      true
Security Enabled                        false
Security Locked                         false
Security Frozen                         true
Security Count Expired                  false
Security Enchanced                      true

Harddisk 1
Name                                    WDC WD10EZEX-00KUWA0
Description                             Disk drive
Vendor                                  (Standard disk drives)
Capacity                                953867 MB
Interface Type                          SATA
Serial Number                           WD-WCC1S4545930
Firmware Revision                       15.01H15
Model Number                            WDC WD10EZEX-00KUWA0
Removable                               false
Support DMA                             true
Support LBA                             true
Support SATA                            true
SATA Generation                         Gen 3
Sector Total                            268435455
Maximum Queue Depth                     31
Highest Supported ATA Version           8
Security Supported                      true
Security Enabled                        false
Security Locked                         false
Security Frozen                         true
Security Count Expired                  false
Security Enchanced                      true

CPU 0
Name                                    AMD FX(tm)-8350 Eight-Core Processor           
Description                             Family 15-6 Model 2-0 Stepping 0
Vendor                                  AuthenticAMD
Max Frequency                           6300 MHz
Start Voltage                           1.1625 V
Min Voltage                             0.0125 V
Max Voltage                             1.55 V
Max Ramp Voltage                        0 V
Max Multiplier                          31.5 X
Start Multiplier                        5 X
L1 Data Cache Size                      16 KB
L1 Data Cache Associativity             4
L1 Data Cache Lines                     1
L1 Data Cache Line Size                 64 Bytes
L1 Instruction Cache Size               64 KB
L1 Instruction Cache Associativity      2
L1 Instruction Cache Lines              1
L1 Instruction Cache Line Size          64 Bytes
L2 Cache Size                           2048 KB
L2 Cache Associativity                  16
L2 Cache Lines                          1
L2 Cache Line Size                      64 Bytes

CPU 1
Name                                    AMD FX(tm)-8350 Eight-Core Processor           
Description                             Family 15-6 Model 2-0 Stepping 0
Vendor                                  AuthenticAMD
Max Frequency                           6300 MHz
Start Voltage                           1.1625 V
Min Voltage                             0.0125 V
Max Voltage                             1.55 V
Max Ramp Voltage                        0 V
Max Multiplier                          31.5 X
Start Multiplier                        5 X
L1 Data Cache Size                      16 KB
L1 Data Cache Associativity             4
L1 Data Cache Lines                     1
L1 Data Cache Line Size                 64 Bytes
L1 Instruction Cache Size               64 KB
L1 Instruction Cache Associativity      2
L1 Instruction Cache Lines              1
L1 Instruction Cache Line Size          64 Bytes
L2 Cache Size                           2048 KB
L2 Cache Associativity                  16
L2 Cache Lines                          1
L2 Cache Line Size                      64 Bytes

CPU 2
Name                                    AMD FX(tm)-8350 Eight-Core Processor           
Description                             Family 15-6 Model 2-0 Stepping 0
Vendor                                  AuthenticAMD
Max Frequency                           6300 MHz
Start Voltage                           1.1625 V
Min Voltage                             0.0125 V
Max Voltage                             1.55 V
Max Ramp Voltage                        0 V
Max Multiplier                          31.5 X
Start Multiplier                        5 X
L1 Data Cache Size                      16 KB
L1 Data Cache Associativity             4
L1 Data Cache Lines                     1
L1 Data Cache Line Size                 64 Bytes
L1 Instruction Cache Size               64 KB
L1 Instruction Cache Associativity      2
L1 Instruction Cache Lines              1
L1 Instruction Cache Line Size          64 Bytes
L2 Cache Size                           2048 KB
L2 Cache Associativity                  16
L2 Cache Lines                          1
L2 Cache Line Size                      64 Bytes

CPU 3
Name                                    AMD FX(tm)-8350 Eight-Core Processor           
Description                             Family 15-6 Model 2-0 Stepping 0
Vendor                                  AuthenticAMD
Max Frequency                           6300 MHz
Start Voltage                           1.1625 V
Min Voltage                             0.0125 V
Max Voltage                             1.55 V
Max Ramp Voltage                        0 V
Max Multiplier                          31.5 X
Start Multiplier                        5 X
L1 Data Cache Size                      16 KB
L1 Data Cache Associativity             4
L1 Data Cache Lines                     1
L1 Data Cache Line Size                 64 Bytes
L1 Instruction Cache Size               64 KB
L1 Instruction Cache Associativity      2
L1 Instruction Cache Lines              1
L1 Instruction Cache Line Size          64 Bytes
L2 Cache Size                           2048 KB
L2 Cache Associativity                  16
L2 Cache Lines                          1
L2 Cache Line Size                      64 Bytes

CPU 4
Name                                    AMD FX(tm)-8350 Eight-Core Processor           
Description                             Family 15-6 Model 2-0 Stepping 0
Vendor                                  AuthenticAMD
Max Frequency                           6300 MHz
Start Voltage                           1.1625 V
Min Voltage                             0.0125 V
Max Voltage                             1.55 V
Max Ramp Voltage                        0 V
Max Multiplier                          31.5 X
Start Multiplier                        5 X
L1 Data Cache Size                      16 KB
L1 Data Cache Associativity             4
L1 Data Cache Lines                     1
L1 Data Cache Line Size                 64 Bytes
L1 Instruction Cache Size               64 KB
L1 Instruction Cache Associativity      2
L1 Instruction Cache Lines              1
L1 Instruction Cache Line Size          64 Bytes
L2 Cache Size                           2048 KB
L2 Cache Associativity                  16
L2 Cache Lines                          1
L2 Cache Line Size                      64 Bytes

CPU 5
Name                                    AMD FX(tm)-8350 Eight-Core Processor           
Description                             Family 15-6 Model 2-0 Stepping 0
Vendor                                  AuthenticAMD
Max Frequency                           6300 MHz
Start Voltage                           1.1625 V
Min Voltage                             0.0125 V
Max Voltage                             1.55 V
Max Ramp Voltage                        0 V
Max Multiplier                          31.5 X
Start Multiplier                        5 X
L1 Data Cache Size                      16 KB
L1 Data Cache Associativity             4
L1 Data Cache Lines                     1
L1 Data Cache Line Size                 64 Bytes
L1 Instruction Cache Size               64 KB
L1 Instruction Cache Associativity      2
L1 Instruction Cache Lines              1
L1 Instruction Cache Line Size          64 Bytes
L2 Cache Size                           2048 KB
L2 Cache Associativity                  16
L2 Cache Lines                          1
L2 Cache Line Size                      64 Bytes

CPU 6
Name                                    AMD FX(tm)-8350 Eight-Core Processor           
Description                             Family 15-6 Model 2-0 Stepping 0
Vendor                                  AuthenticAMD
Max Frequency                           6300 MHz
Start Voltage                           1.1625 V
Min Voltage                             0.0125 V
Max Voltage                             1.55 V
Max Ramp Voltage                        0 V
Max Multiplier                          31.5 X
Start Multiplier                        5 X
L1 Data Cache Size                      16 KB
L1 Data Cache Associativity             4
L1 Data Cache Lines                     1
L1 Data Cache Line Size                 64 Bytes
L1 Instruction Cache Size               64 KB
L1 Instruction Cache Associativity      2
L1 Instruction Cache Lines              1
L1 Instruction Cache Line Size          64 Bytes
L2 Cache Size                           2048 KB
L2 Cache Associativity                  16
L2 Cache Lines                          1
L2 Cache Line Size                      64 Bytes

CPU 7
Name                                    AMD FX(tm)-8350 Eight-Core Processor           
Description                             Family 15-6 Model 2-0 Stepping 0
Vendor                                  AuthenticAMD
Max Frequency                           6300 MHz
Start Voltage                           1.1625 V
Min Voltage                             0.0125 V
Max Voltage                             1.55 V
Max Ramp Voltage                        0 V
Max Multiplier                          31.5 X
Start Multiplier                        5 X
L1 Data Cache Size                      16 KB
L1 Data Cache Associativity             4
L1 Data Cache Lines                     1
L1 Data Cache Line Size                 64 Bytes
L1 Instruction Cache Size               64 KB
L1 Instruction Cache Associativity      2
L1 Instruction Cache Lines              1
L1 Instruction Cache Line Size          64 Bytes
L2 Cache Size                           2048 KB
L2 Cache Associativity                  16
L2 Cache Lines                          1
L2 Cache Line Size                      64 Bytes

HTLink 0
HT0 Multiplier                          11 X
HT0 Width In                            16 bits
HT0 Width Out                           16 bits
HT0 Max Width In                        16 bits
HT0 Max Width Out                       16 bits
HT1 Multiplier                          1 X
HT1 Width In                            8 bits
HT1 Width Out                           8 bits
HT1 Max Width In                        8 bits
HT1 Max Width Out                       8 bits
HT2 Multiplier                          1 X
HT2 Width In                            8 bits
HT2 Width Out                           8 bits
HT2 Max Width In                        8 bits
HT2 Max Width Out                       8 bits
HT3 Multiplier                          1 X
HT3 Width In                            8 bits
HT3 Width Out                           8 bits
HT3 Max Width In                        8 bits
HT3 Max Width Out                       8 bits

Memory 0
Name                                    Physical Memory 0
Description                             
Vendor                                  Team Group Inc.
Capacity                                8192 MB
Max Bandwidth                           10.7 GB/s
Part Number                             Vulcan-1600       
Serial Number                           0
Data Width                              64 bits
Bus Frequency                           685.714 MHz
Slot Location                           Slot 2

Memory 1
Name                                    Physical Memory 1
Description                             
Vendor                                  Team Group Inc.
Capacity                                8192 MB
Max Bandwidth                           10.7 GB/s
Part Number                             Vulcan-1600       
Serial Number                           0
Data Width                              64 bits
Bus Frequency                           685.714 MHz
Slot Location                           Slot 3

Monitor 0
Name                                    Generic PnP Monitor
Description                             Generic PnP Monitor
Vendor                                  (Standard monitor types)
Screen Width                            1600 pixels
Screen Height                           900 pixels
Max Width                               1600 pixels
Max Height                              900 pixels
Refresh Rate                            0 Hz
Pixels Per XLogical Inch                96 pixels
Pixels Per YLogical Inch                96 pixels

USB Controller 0
Name                                    EHCI USB Controller
Description                             EHCI USB Controller
Vendor                                  AuthenticAMD

USB Controller 1
Name                                    EHCI USB Controller
Description                             EHCI USB Controller
Vendor                                  AuthenticAMD

USB Controller 2
Name                                    EHCI USB Controller
Description                             EHCI USB Controller
Vendor                                  AuthenticAMD

USB Controller 3
Name                                    OHCI USB Controller
Description                             OHCI USB Controller
Vendor                                  AuthenticAMD
Enhanced (101- or 102-key)              

USB Controller 4
Name                                    OHCI USB Controller
Description                             OHCI USB Controller
Vendor                                  AuthenticAMD

USB Controller 5
Name                                    OHCI USB Controller
Description                             OHCI USB Controller
Vendor                                  AuthenticAMD

USB Controller 6
Name                                    OHCI USB Controller
Description                             OHCI USB Controller
Vendor                                  AuthenticAMD
```

Comment: try unplugging all the other hard drives you have, and restart, see what happens.

Comment: Is it getting the error from the drive, or from the BIOS? That error is usually not the type of error a BIOS will give.  Ctrl+Alt+Del is tell tale that this is a Microsoft issue and your BIOS is loading something from the drive that is from Microsoft.  Did you up or downgrade windows recently?  Major updates like a service pack?  Additional windows installation somewhere?  Did you run any programs that altered your drive like a partition program?  The working on boot, but not on restart definitely makes this one tricky.

Comment: You have a nonbootable USB stick/HD plugged in, or a nonbootable CD/DVD/BR disc left in your optical drive. Remove the media.

Comment: This error message comes from the Windows loader, not from the BIOS. I am using `grub` to dual boot. I have rearranged my partitions, so that the Windows C: partition, formerly the third partition, is now the second partition. When trying to boot Windows, the above error results. I know it is on the right disk because it says "Setting partition type to 0x7" and empirically this means that it has read (not set) the type of the current partition and found it to be of type "7" (NTFS). Not sure what else is going wrong...

Answer (score 3):

Go into your BIOS and change the startup order. Make sure your harddrive is the first drive it tries to boot from. This will make sure it won't try to boot from any USB drive or DVD, etc.

New BIOSses usually have a key to access the boot menu anyway which you can use to boot from different media in the case you need to install windows etc.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and discovered that the mouse I had connected to through a USB port was causing the problem. I did follow the suggestion above to make sure the first thing to Boot would be from disc, but after that, it still gave me the same error message you received. I was about to give up when I tried unplugging my mouse and the computer then booted from the disc.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found that the partition which I had my OS on is not active.
When I activated the partition, I was able to boot as normal.
Try this I think it may help:

**If you can remove your hard disk**

- Remove the hard disk and connect it to another working PC
- Go to **Start** type **Create and format disk partition** and select it
- You will enter into **disk management**
- Find the hard disk in which OS was not detected
  (the one in which "An operating system was not detected" message was displayed)
- Right click on it and select **Mark partition as active**
- Reconnect the disk to your original system and start as normal

**Using diskpart**

- Insert a Windows disk into the DVD drive (doesn't matter which version, as long as it's >= Windows 7)
- Boot into the DVD and select **Repair your PC**
- Select **Advanced Options** and **Command Prompt**

Type the following:

```
diskpart
list disk 
select disk 0 (select your hard disk num listed in list disk here mine is disk 0)
list partition
find the partition in which your OS has been installed (you can find by looking at the size of the partition; here my OS partition is partition 3)
select partition 3
active
exit
```

That's it, you can reboot your system.

Comment: Please use punctuation and `Shift`. Your answer is completely unreadable. Use the *Edit* button below it.

Answer (score 0):

Since "Windows Repair" couldn't help me, I decided to use `diskpart`.
`Diskpart` is a Windows built-in utility to work with disks. I booted from an installation media, selected "Repair", went to the command prompt and typed the following:

```
diskpart
lis dis          // helped me to find my disk
sel dis 0        // when typing "lis dis", my disk number was 0
active
exit             // leaving the diskpart
exit             // leaving the command prompt
```

After, I rebooted and my Windows was finally working!

Comment: This is a working answer, but it is not detailed enough. Could you perhaps post commands with code blocks and I will remove my downvote. You can use the `Edit` button below your answer to change it.